# Return other row if condition not does not match in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Select country, price, cost
from table1
where user_id = 1 and is_enabled = 1 and country = 'IN' and sender_id = 'TEXT'
```

The above query will return the records if where conditions are met.
Now, I want query to return records even if the conditions are not met but by removing the sender_id from the where condition i.e

```
Select country, price, cost
from table1
where user_id = 1 and is_enabled = 1 and country = 'IN'
```

Please help!

I tried using CASE When but didn't achieved the result.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Adding an example that demonstrates the desired result for a given set of rows within `table1` may help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This should help if you need records anyways.

```
SELECT country, price, cost FROM table1
WHERE user_id = 1 AND is_enabled = 1 AND country = 'IN' OR NOT sender_id = 'TEXT'
```

In another use case, you can get the sender_id column if matched by using the below query but it will give you null for all unmatched records.

```
SELECT country, price, cost, CASE WHEN sender_id <> 'TEXT' THEN sender_id ELSE NULL END AS sender_id
FROM table1 WHERE user_id = 1 AND is_enabled = 1 AND country = 'IN'
```